# How to display a 360 panorama from android application

Tags: android, panoramas

I  want to display a panorama from my android application, this panorama is online and I have its url I load it on a webview but it won't work properly. It just appears a portion of it, and it won't turn or move upside down. I have no idea where to start with this, can you point me at the right direction? thank you in advance

Comment: Have you using an intent targeting the Google+ app? This will open a new activity of course.

Comment: No, the only thing I've done is to load the webview with the url.It's my first time dealing with panoramas and such, How would I do what you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research I found out this library it is still pretty new but sure can help you start with something. I'm posting it just to save time for other searchers! cheers 
[PanoramaGl](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/)

Comment: Did you have any success?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation in Kotlin, but I needed to get the image from a URL.  I resolved it using Picasso. I leave this here for future reference:

```
    val options = VrPanoramaView.Options()
    val url = "https://urltoyourimage.com/image.jpg"

    Picasso.get().load(url)
        .into(object : Target {
            override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
                options.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_MONO
                vrPanoramaView.loadImageFromBitmap(bitmap, options)
            }

            override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                print(e?.localizedMessage)
            }

            override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
                print(placeHolderDrawable)
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add dependency in gradle (app-level)

   `compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.80.0'`
2. Add `VrPanoramaView` in your xml and get a reference via `findViewById()` method in android
3. Below is the code for loading the image from asset.

`VrPanoramaView` takes input as Bitmap so we need to first
convert it into right format. Here, the `loadPhotoSphere` functions
in called in `onCreate()`

```
private void loadPhotoSphere() {
  VrPanoramaView.Options options = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
  InputStream inputStream = null;

  try {
      inputStream = assetManager.open("image.jpg");
      options.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
      mVRPanoramaView.loadImageFromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream), options);
      inputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Read about Google VR SDK for Android [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started)

Comment: it is workin on only 19. version and above. Do you know how can we us earlier versions ?