# 360 Image Viewer with motion & touch in Android

Tags: android, 360-panorama, 360-panorama-viewer

I am implementing a concept to show an image in 360 view such as available in Facebook Android Application.

For that, I have explore so many tutorials & Github repositories.

Please help any work around If anybody has done in Android.

Thanks.

The links I have explored till now.

[ProgrammedImageView](https://github.com/gjiazhe/PanoramaImageView)

[Panorama360](https://github.com/acodexm/Panorama360)

[MD360Player4Android](https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android)

[panorama-view](https://github.com/rjuszczyk/panorama-view)

Comment: possible duplicate at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612058/how-to-display-a-360-panorama-from-android-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a 360 panorama from android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612058/how-to-display-a-360-panorama-from-android-application)